# How do I stop CSV from truncating long numbers?

Tags: php, csv, formatting

I am using PHP languanges to do the export csv file function. All data convert is correct, but if the long number data, it will automatic convert to formatting number in the csv file, for example `9.9102E+11`. May I know how stop CSV from truncating long numbers? Hope someone can guide me. Thanks.

Below is my long number variable code:

```html
$content .= $row['identify'].",";
```

The error `Passport/IC No` column output show me like below :

[image: output]

What I've tried,but it doesn't work:

```html
$content .= strval($row['identify']).",";
```

Comment: add a `'` in front of the formula

Comment: I have tried it to add in my code, but the number show me like '523512253215

Comment: Put the number in quotes, like `"523512253215"` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely make sure it's being output as a string. Apparently, it's on scientific notation. It's not an unfamiliar form, as you know. It's just not human-readable for detail. If you want you can look up the program you're using and check it for an option set on the subject at hand. This should be restful. So, please tell me if this works.

[BTW, here's a helpful link](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

Comment: I use this $content .= number_format($row['identify']).","; still can't work

Comment: @PiNetworkCrytocurrency Use: `$content = number_format($row['identify'],10) . ".";`

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the scientific notation in the raw csv file, or in spreadsheet software like Excel?

If you only see this in Excel you can just reformat the column (csv files have no formatting).

If you really want to export that field as 'text' (i.e. let Excel treat it as text) then you can use `="12345678"`.